# Python Boto3 Cross account transfer between s3 error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I have the following :

1. Bucket name for s3 bucket in source account
   from where I will grab the files.
2. IAM role for destination account
   and also the s3 bucket name for destination account where   I will
   drop the files.
3. I created a user and role in my personal account and
   also saved the access key and secret access key.While creating role I used another AWS account option.

I want to transfer files from source s3 bucket to destination s3 bucket.

I created a user on my personal account and gave full s3 access and full sagemaker access and I added the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:iam::***********:role/destinationrole"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

I created role on my personal account for sagemaker.In the Trust relationships I added the user I created above and attached the same policy as above

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::***********:role/destinationrole"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I am trying to generate temporary credentials

```
import boto3
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::***********:role/destinationrole,
    RoleSessionName="test"
)
```

Not sure if the steps I am following are right, but when run the above script I am getting the error :**An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::my_account:assumed-role//SageMaker is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::destination account:role/destinationrole**

I need to move files from source account s3 bucket to destination account s3 bucket. source account has just provided the bucket name and destination account has provided the IAM role and bucket name . Source account has updated the bucket policy on their end allowing the destination account to pull the data. I am lost on what credentials to use and how to assume role and get temp credentials.

Comment: Are you running that Python/boto3 script on SageMaker which has different credentials to the ones you gave permission to assume the destination role?

Comment: yes running it on sagemaker. I have never used sage maker before. does it have different credentials?

Comment: The SageMaker service operates on your behalf. You give it permission to do that via an execution role. It may be advisable to read up on how SageMaker roles work.

Comment: also, if you are transferring files from one s3 bucket to another in different accounts, you need to update the source S3 bucket's policy to allow the other account to pull data from it.

Comment: yes updated the source s3 bucket policy.

Comment: also I don't have to use sage maker, I can run the script locally on my machine. just want to be able to assume roles and transfer files

Comment: I need to move files from source account  s3 bucket to destination account s3 bucket. source account has just provided the bucket name and destination account has provided the IAM role and bucket name . Source account has updated the bucket policy on their end allowing the destination account to pull the data. I am lost on what credentials to use and how to assume role and get temp credentials.

Comment: Make sure the SageMaker role has the permission to assume the cross-account role. When using your local user and it shows the same error, you should get back to other account owner for troubleshooting. The other account probably has not allowed your whole account to access the bucket, just one role/user, i guess/hope :)

Comment: @f7o I  have attached the same policy as user to the sage maker role which is permission to assume the destination account role. But I am still getting the error. In my code above in the role arn am I using the right role which is the destinationaccount?